# How to get Hijiri Date Picker using Angular Js in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

am getting Hijiri date using javascript but i want to write Hijiri date using angularJS,
i want to create angular directive for that hijiri date

this is javascript code am using to get Hijiri Date , how to convert this to angular and create directive

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var cal1 = new Calendar(),
    cal2 = new Calendar(true, 0, false, true),
    date1 = document.getElementById('date-1'),
    date2 = document.getElementById('date-2'),
    cal1Mode = cal1.isHijriMode(),
    cal2Mode = cal2.isHijriMode();

    document.getElementById('cal-1').appendChild(cal1.getElement());
    document.getElementById('cal-2').appendChild(cal2.getElement());
    cal1.hide();
    cal2.hide();
    setDateFields();

    cal1.callback = function () {
        if (cal1Mode !== cal1.isHijriMode()) {
            cal2.disableCallback(true);
            cal2.changeDateMode();
            cal2.disableCallback(false);
            cal1Mode = cal1.isHijriMode();
            cal2Mode = cal2.isHijriMode();
        }
        else
            cal2.setTime(cal1.getTime());
        setDateFields();
    };

    cal2.callback = function () {
        if (cal2Mode !== cal2.isHijriMode()) {
            cal1.disableCallback(true);
            cal1.changeDateMode();
            cal1.disableCallback(false);
            cal1Mode = cal1.isHijriMode();
            cal2Mode = cal2.isHijriMode();
        }
        else
            cal1.setTime(cal2.getTime());
        setDateFields();
    };

    function setDateFields() {
        date1.value = cal1.getDate().getDateString();
        date2.value = cal2.getDate().getDateString();
    }

    function showCal1() {
        if (cal1.isHidden()) cal1.show();
        else cal1.hide();
    }

    function showCal2() {
        if (cal2.isHidden()) cal2.show();
        else cal2.hide();
    }

</script>
```

html

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="10"  ng-model="EmployeeSave.HijriDate" onclick="showCal2();" id="date-2" />
```

Comment: just FYI: using keith-wood calendar picker for Hijri is much more easier than this way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **moment-hijri** (https://github.com/xsoh/moment-hijri) it is simple and easy as compare to what you are doing.

```
npm install moment-hijri
```

and use it like :

```
var moment = require('moment-hijri');
moment().format('iYYYY/iM/iD');
```